# Does use structs direct in functions uses more resources than pass them in parameters in C?

Tags: c, gcc, embedded

here is my question.

Is there a good way to uses global context structures in embedded c program ?

I mean is it better to pass them in parameters of function or directly use the global reference inside the function ? Or there is no differences ?

Example:

```
Context_t myContext; // is a structure with a lot of members

void function1(Context_t *ctx)
{
  ctx->x = 1;
}

or

void function2(void)
{
   myContext.x = 1;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Create a small test program using both methods, compile it, and look at the generated code.

Comment: The general tip is to make everything as local as possible.

Comment: I think that passing a global context variable in parameter, regardless of resources, is something you shouldn't do. If it is global, then use it as a global variable. If you don't need it to be global, avoid it

Comment: Your context is single-instance anyway,  so passing a pointer just wastes stack space -> access it directly. And btw globals are often fine for embedded code

Comment: with a global on a constrained system your memory usage is fixed/known.  declaring it as local and passing it on, the passing it on is just a pointer, doesnt cost much but even there your stack usage (from the struct and maybe the pointers) is more variable than it would have been.  one structure no biggie but do this habitually and you have a problem of determining chip size (memory) and insuring the stack doesnt crash into data.  so slightly slower passing the pointer, and some/slight variability with stack consumption.  most likely a wash if you focus on this one struct, in the noise.

Comment: Required reading if you believe that a global is ever acceptable: http://www.embedded.com/electronics-blogs/break-points/4025723/A-pox-on-globals.  But if you made a decision to make it global, ill-advised as that may be, you gain nothing by accessing it through a local reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Where to allocate variables is a program design decision, not a performance decision.**

On modern systems there is not going to be much of a performance difference between your two versions.

When passing a lot of different parameters, rather than just one single pointer as in this case, there could be a performance difference. Older systems, most notably 8 bit MCUs with crappy compilers, could benefit quite a lot from using file scope variables when it comes to performance. Mostly since old legacy architectures like PIC, AVR, HC08, 8051 etc had very limited stack and register resources. If you have to maintain such old stuff, then file scope variables *will* improve performance.

That being said, you should allocate variables where it makes since. If the purpose of your code unit is to process `Context_t` allocated elsewhere, it should get passed as a pointer. If `Context_t` is private data that the caller does not need to know about, you could allocate it at file scope.

Please note that there is never a reason to declare "global" variables at file scope. All your file scope variables should have internal linkage. That is, they should be declared as `static`. This is perfectly fine practice in most embedded systems, particularly single core, bare metal MCU applications.

However, note that file scope variables are not thread-safe and causes complications on multi-process systems. If you are for example using a RTOS, you should minimize the amount of such variables.

Comment: Not only a matter of RTOS, but of any multithreading capable OS/environment... And: the remaining globals (if not thread_local) must be protected against race conditions - via mutexes, semaphores, ..., by use of lock-less algorithms, or by assuring that these are only accessed by one single thread -- the latter likely being the most difficult/dangerous to apply...

Comment: @Aconcagua This is tagged embedded, so multi-threading environments are unlikely. Depends on your definition of "embedded" of course.

Comment: Thanks for answers, in my case I talk about embedded system with no RTOS, no multi threading system.

Comment: It is not a matter of "modern systems" and "old stuff", just a matter of architecture and high-end vs low-end devices. PIC, AVR and 8051derivitives are still used in current production and frequently used in new designs.  The code should suit the architecture that is true, and most 8 bit devices have significant resource and architectural constraints and were designed long ago, but that does not mean all code on them is in legacy maintenance or that the compilers are antique and incapable of sophisticated optimisation.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly to your question.  If you are going to have the global then use it as a global directly.  Having one function use it as a global and then pass it down requires setup on the caller, the consumption of the resource (register or stack) for the parameter, and slight savings on the function itself:

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned int a;
    unsigned int b;
    unsigned int c;
    unsigned int d;
    unsigned int e;
    unsigned int f;
    unsigned int g;
    unsigned int h;
    unsigned int i;
    unsigned int j;
} SO_STRUCT;
SO_STRUCT so;


unsigned int fun1 ( SO_STRUCT s )
{
    return(s.a+s.g);
}
unsigned int fun2 ( SO_STRUCT *s )
{
    return(s->a+s->g);
}
unsigned int fun3 ( void )
{
    return(so.a+so.g);
}


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <fun1>:
   0:   e24dd010    sub sp, sp, #16
   4:   e24dc004    sub r12, sp, #4
   8:   e98c000f    stmib   r12, {r0, r1, r2, r3}
   c:   e59d3018    ldr r3, [sp, #24]
  10:   e59d0000    ldr r0, [sp]
  14:   e28dd010    add sp, sp, #16
  18:   e0800003    add r0, r0, r3
  1c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

00000020 <fun2>:
  20:   e5902000    ldr r2, [r0]
  24:   e5900018    ldr r0, [r0, #24]
  28:   e0820000    add r0, r2, r0
  2c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

00000030 <fun3>:
  30:   e59f300c    ldr r3, [pc, #12]   ; 44 <fun3+0x14>
  34:   e5930000    ldr r0, [r3]
  38:   e5933018    ldr r3, [r3, #24]
  3c:   e0800003    add r0, r0, r3
  40:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
  44:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0
```

the caller to fun2 would have to load the address of the struct to pass it in so in this case the extra consumption is we lost a register as a parameter, since there were so few parameters, it was a wash, for a single call from a single higher function.  if you continued to nest this the best you could do is keep handing down the register:

```
unsigned int funx ( SO_STRUCT *s );
unsigned int fun2 ( SO_STRUCT *s )
{
    return(funx(s)+3);
}

Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <fun2>:
   0:   e92d4010    push    {r4, lr}
   4:   ebfffffe    bl  0 <funx>
   8:   e8bd4010    pop {r4, lr}
   c:   e2800003    add r0, r0, #3
  10:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

so no matter whether the struct was originally global or local to some function, in this case if I call the next function and pass by reference the first caller has to setup the parameter, in this case with arm that is a register r0, so stack pointer math or a load of an address into r0.  r0 goes to fun2() and can be used directly by reference to get at items assuming the function is simple enough it doesnt have to evict out to the stack.  Then calling funx() with the same pointer, fun2 does NOT have to load r0 (in this simplified doesnt get too much better than this case) and funx() can reference items from r0 directly.  had fun2 and funx used the global directly they both would resemble fun3 above where each function would have a load to get the address and a word to store the address

one would hope multiple functions in a file would share but dont make that assumption:

```
unsigned int fun3 ( void )
{
    return(so.a+so.g);
}
unsigned int funz ( void )
{
    return(so.a+so.h);
}

00000000 <fun3>:
   0:   e59f300c    ldr r3, [pc, #12]   ; 14 <fun3+0x14>
   4:   e5930000    ldr r0, [r3]
   8:   e5933018    ldr r3, [r3, #24]
   c:   e0800003    add r0, r0, r3
  10:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
  14:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0

00000018 <funz>:
  18:   e59f300c    ldr r3, [pc, #12]   ; 2c <funz+0x14>
  1c:   e5930000    ldr r0, [r3]
  20:   e593301c    ldr r3, [r3, #28]
  24:   e0800003    add r0, r0, r3
  28:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
  2c:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0
```

as your function gets more complicated though this optimization goes away (simply passing r0 down as the first parameter).  So you end up storing and then retreiving the address to the struct so it costs a stack location and a store and some loads where direct to the global would be a flash/.text location and a load, so slightly cheaper.

if on a system where the parameters are on the stack then continuing to pass the pointer does not have a chance at that optimization you have to keep copying the pointer to the stack for each nested call...

So as far as your direct question there is no correct answer other than it depends.  And you would need to be really really tight on a performance or resource budget to worry about a premature optimization like that.

As far as consumption, globals have the benefit on a very tightly constrained system of being fixed and known at compile time what their consumption is.  Where having local variables as a habit in particular structures, is going to create a lot of stack use which is dynamic and much harder to measure (can change each line of code you add or remove too, so spend a week trying to determine the use, then add a line and you could gain nothing to a few percent to tens of percent).  At the same time a one time or few time use variable or structure MIGHT be better served locally, depends on how deep in the nested functions, if at the end then doesnt cost much if declared locally at the top function then it costs the same as being global but is now on the stack and not measured at compile time.  One struct, ehhh, no biggie, a habit, that is when it matters.

So to your specific question it cannot be determined ahead of time and cannot make a general rule that it is "faster" to pass by reference or use directly as one can easily create use cases that demonstrate each being true.  The wee bitty improvement would come from knowing your memory consumption at compile time (global) vs runtime (local).  But your question was not about local vs global was about access to the global.

Answer (score 0):

Much better to pass a reference to the structure than modify the structure as a global.  Passing a reference makes it visible the function is (potentially) changing the structure.

From a performance standpoint there won't be a measurable difference.

If the number of structure accesses is significant, passing the reference can also result in significantly smaller code.

Comment: How would passing references/pointers make the code smaller??? Accessing globals directly is just reading from or writing to the memory - using a pointer - well, again we want to read/write memory, but before being able to do that, we need to dereference the pointer first, which needs additional instructions...

Comment: @Aconcagua it depends on the compiler and architecture, but if you pass a reference and you can encode all loads as [Rn + #imm] (reference plus an offset small enough to fit in encoded instruction) then it may be smaller than repeatedly loading the address of the variable+offset.  This requires the compiler to be poor enough that it can't recognize the addresses being loaded and condense them all.

Comment: @RussSchultz That must be a *very* poor compiler not being able to compile `global.member` into the same immediate load instruction as in your comment...

Comment: @Aconcagua Registers are often a very limited resource, and the compiler won't want to spill them to memory to free one for use unless necessary.  There is no reason to load the `global.` address into a register because it is _constant_ and there's zero or minimal performance penalty directly embedding a constant address in an instruction -- the instruction merely becomes a few bytes larger.  Passing the `global.` address as an argument _forces_ the compiler to register it and use the typically smaller [base-reg+offset] addressing mode in all references to `global.` .

Answer (score 0):

Global variables are generally preferred to be avoided, there are plenty of reasons to it. While with global variables some find it easy to share a single resource between many functions, but there are flipsides to it. Be it ease of code understanding, be it dependencies and tight coupling of variables. Many a times we end up using libraries, and with modules that are linked *dynamically*, it is troublesome if different libraries have their own instances of global variables.

So, with direct reference to your question, I would prefer

```
void function1(Context_t *ctx)
```

against anything that involves changing a global variable.
But again, if the necessary precautions are taken in terms of tight coupling of global variables and functions, it is okay to go with existing implementation which has global variables, rather than scrapping the whole tested thing and start off again.